# How do I unit test angular controller that calls async services with caolan async lib

Tags: angularjs, sinon, async.js

I have two angular controllers that async load resources via multiple services. The first is with direct promises, the second a simplified example using caolan async library https://github.com/caolan/async

Sample code below, live fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/42taoLet/4/

```
var userid="1";
mod.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,User,Group) {
  User.get({user:userid}).then(function(user) {
     Group.get({group:user.group}).then(function(group) {
        $scope.group = group;
     });
  });
})
.controller('ACtrl',function($scope,User,Group) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(cb){
        User.get({user:userid}).then(cb);
    },
    function(user,cb) {
        Group.get({group:user.group}).then(cb);
    }
  ],function(group) {
    $scope.group = group;
  });
});
```

For unit testing purposes, I stubbed out `User` and `Group`.

```
describe('MyCtrl', function(){
  var scope, user, group, $q, userdefer, groupdefer;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');
    inject(function($rootScope,$controller,_$q_) {
       scope = $rootScope;
       $q = _$q_;
       user = {get:sinon.stub()};
       userdefer = $q.defer();
       user.get.returns(userdefer.promise);
       group = {get:sinon.stub()};
       groupdefer = $q.defer();
       group.get.returns(groupdefer.promise);
       $controller('MyCtrl',{$scope:scope,User:user,Group:group});
       userdefer.resolve({id:"1",group:"25"});
       groupdefer.resolve({name:"AdminGroup"});
       scope.$digest();
     });
  });
  it('should set $scope.group to an object',function(){
      expect(scope.group).toEqual({name:"AdminGroup"});
  });
});
```

The test for 'ACtrl' is identical.

The test for `MyCtrl` passes; the one for `ACtrl` fails, because it immediately sends it off to an async queue that I cannot flush.

How do I get the `beforeEach()` to complete all caolan/async callbacks **before** passing control back to the actual tests?

How do I get this to flush the calls - like `$httpBackend.flush()` or `$timeout.flush()` - so it completes? .